# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: apsillers]
[image: ArtOfCode]
[image: Zizouz212]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections shortly after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem - help them and work with them. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats to our new moderators!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks guys! I'm happy to be on the team.

A few notes for you about what I think this is going to be like, and my intentions.

I'm going to go with a proactive and approachable strategy. If I see something that I need to do something about, I'll do something about it. However, me being a mod doesn't promote me to being master of you all - if anything, I'm here to serve, not boss. I'm still the same guy you all interacted with through our first month, and I'd like to keep the same relationship with the people here. To that end:

- **Tell me things.**
  If you think I've done something wrong, missed something out, made a mistake, etc etc, tell me. Drop a message in [The Bikeshed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25118/the-bikeshed), or post here on Meta - I'd rather know what you're all thinking than continue happily on thinking I've done everything right. I'm human. I'm *going* to make mistakes.
- **Flag things.**
  This is still early days for us as a community, and while we don't have masses of stuff coming in I'd like to make use of that. Our flag queue is going to be pretty empty; if you see something that you *might* flag but aren't sure, just flag it. Again, I'd rather deal with more flags and have a better community for it.

  If you can make me laugh with your flag reasons, while still telling me the problem and what you want done, I'll give you some Karma points free.

I'll be approachable and transparent - and if you think I'm not being enough of either, call me out on it.

I'm looking forward to it!

Answer (score 6):

Well, thanks for the trust.

I think ArtOfCode said all the relevant stuff: Notify us if our help is needed, through the chat, Meta-posts or flags.

Do you think something in the community goes wrong? Bring it to our attention!

I hope this community will have a nice future and I look forward to it. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Funny enough, I got an email about this right after I had been yelled at by someone in airport security. I’ll just quote if you really want to read it:

> Right now, I'm in Norway, and earlier today I went on a domestic flight between Molde and Oslo, in Norway. Of course, I'm 15, and I'm traveling with my younger brother, so naturally during the security check, they asked for documents that would allows us to travel alone. Right afterwards, this one lady just popped out of nowhere, and started searching my bag. Apparently, I had a small bottle of hand sanitizer that I keep in my bag (the bag was my school bag) and she starts yelling at me about how I need to always take liquids out of my bag for like 10 minutes (Wasn't a problem during my trip from Toronto to Oslo)... Right before I was about to get onto the plane, I got your email and it literally cheered me up. I'm writing this response from my phone while getting my bags. :)

Regardless, I’m now a moderator (yaay, but will I die?)… and as [someone noted something about me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25118?m=22699528#22699528), I’ll say this to sum up all about me and my actions:

#### [Woobbbbbbuuuufffffeeeeetttttttt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0NFIL2bV3M) - Yep, a youtube video too for awesomeness

<sup>By the way, Wobbuffet is English for the phrase, *”That’s the way it is ma’am!”* according to my friend’s brother.</sup>

Essentially, I still be playful, helpful, cooperative and destructive in my own Zizouz ways. Don't be scared to approach me, ask me anything, I don't have any teeth like you probably saw in the video (what! You barely watched it?). Call me out, give me feedback

I just want to say that the team that was selected is sure to be amazing, and that many of the other candidates are excellent in what they do. I wouldn’t be surprised if we twisted the heads of some people at SE with the quality and number of candidates that this site had nominated. The team is amazing, and I'm sure that we can work extraordinarily well together.

Comment: We need to have [a talk.](http://faqsmedia.ign.com/faqs/image/ani202.gif)

Comment: @TheWob-buffet Yes indeed. Your avatar is fairly questionable. Any suggestions on how we should do this? Neither of us can place an attack, so what shall we make this a contest of?

Comment: Do you play any Smash Brothers games? Only thing I'm good at. Or pokemon showdown, more relevent... However, i am accepting surrenders or not caring and going on with life so KeyboardFire can wake up being scared that I'm a mod in his dreams.

Comment: @TheWob-buffet Waaaatttt! I've got Pokemon. And Pokemon. And more Pokemon. And EVEN MORE POKEMON!!!

Comment: Okay, I can attempt to play you with my troll team, or we can play Super Smash Bros. with pokemon only (not letting the idea go just yet)

Comment: In any case, continue to contact me at my email that I definitely did not create for this occasion specifically: realwobbuffet@gmail.com

Comment: OH MY GOD you're learning swift? I'm using swift for the first time in making my first major iOS app, hooray for people who don't despise apple that much. I like apple personally just because of their app reviewing system.